# Remove an entry from nginx error_log

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I am using nginx as reverse proxy with my application. I have a use case of geth attach.
Users can do geth attach https://dns-name:port/api-key to get the geth console.
Example:

> geth attach https://google-service.net:6000/Yik987hjk

In case of error nginx error_log shows this apikey.
Example:

> 11:32:14 [error] 48#0: *12479669 connect() failed (111: Connection
>   refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 1*4.***.****.*01,
>   server: _, request: "POST /api-key HTTP/1.1",
>   upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:******", host: "*******.******.****.com:port"

I read the nginx docs, there is no way to use log format for error_log.
Is there any way to configure this error_log. I do not want to show this api-key in logs.

Answer (score 2):

**Simpler config example:** Just add a line into your nginx config file `error_log off`  but remember with this your error_log file is not created

```
http {
  access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

  server {
    listen 80;
    location /app1 {
      error_log off; # <----- this WILL work
      proxy_pass http://example.com;
    }
    (...)
  }

}
```